# MongoCXX - handling a cursor from distinct

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I think it should be fairly obvious what I'm trying to do here - query a collection m_coll, and get all unique values of Density from that collection. However, the thing it's returning is an element, not a full document, so you can't seem to key it, and it screams at you, namely `C++ exception with description "unset document::element" thrown in the test body.`. What modification needs to be made to make this work?

```
std::vector<int> MongoReader::getLvlOne()
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document empty;
    mongocxx::cursor cursor = m_coll.distinct("Density",empty.view());
    for (bsoncxx::document::view doc : cursor)
    {
        ret.push_back(doc["Density"].get_int32());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `.distinct()` does not return a "cursor". In all drivers it's basically a "list". Without looking at the CXX documentation it's probably a "vector". So you are assigning to an incorrect type. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really obscure and poorly documented, for which I apologize.  I've opened a Jira ticket, [CXX-1406](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-1406), about improving docs and providing an example.

The `distinct` method returns a cursor, but it only ever provides a single document that looks like this:

```
{
   "values" : [ "A", "B" ],
   "ok" : 1
}
```

That's just exactly what the [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/#return-distinct-values-for-a-field) database command returns.

You can see an example of usage in the [tests for distinct](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/src/mongocxx/test/collection.cpp#L1553-L1569).

There's a ticket, [CXX-1126](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-1126), for a better API, but it would be a breaking change, so we're not sure when we'll address it.